# Sending aggressive/instant transaction, setting gas

Tags: nodejs, eip-1559, 1inch-dex-aggregator

I'm trading through the 1inch API and I want to speed up my transactions. I need my transactions to be completed in <10 seconds, like the aggressive mode in the 1inch interface, but I'm not sure how to set the gas.

[image: 1inch aggresivve mode]

I am using this example for trading: https://docs.1inch.io/docs/aggregation-protocol/guide/quick-start#do-exchange

Comment: In the link you posted. I would guess that the gas setting are in the rawTransaction